# Excel formula string shuffle

Tags: excel

I have a string of three characters which I would like to shuffle based on a parttren (position number), This needs to be done using formulas in Excel. Any Ideas.

String = "ABC"

ColA is the input number parttern

ColB is the expected output based on the formula.

```
ColA:ColB
123 : ABC
132 : ACB
213 : BAC
231 : BCA
312 : CAB
321 : CBA
```

regards

Comment: Try looking up the MID() function

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you data is Column `A` the following will work:

```
=MID("ABC", MID(A1,1,1),1) & MID("ABC", MID(A1,2,1),1) & MID("ABC", MID(A1,3,1),1)
```

This is three formulas concatenated together. The first `MID("ABC", MID(A1,1,1),1)` Gets the first character position from Column A and then grabs that character from the string. The second gets the second position and then grabs that position's character, and the third gets the third character's position then grabs that character. It all gets concatenated and Bob's your uncle.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way, using `CHAR`:

```
=CHAR(64+LEFT(A1))&CHAR(64+MID(A1,2,1))&CHAR(64+RIGHT(A1))
```